# Implmentation of hasNext method in an inner class of Java

Tags: java, iterator

My texted book that uses an inner class as an iterator says that the method `hasNext` is just return `current < this.size;`  where `current` is the `current index`. But if the size is 3 and the index is 2, there wouldn't be a next value, so why wouldn't it be `< size - 1`

Comment: If I have an array of length 1, there is only one valid index (and it isn't `1`).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which Iterator implementation your are referring to but talking about java implementation it is like below:

```
public boolean hasNext() {          
   return cursor != size; //cursor is the index of next element to be fetched
}
```

So the implementation you are referring to I believe `current` actually refers to the element to be fetched next.

Lets take your example:

```
Size : 3
current : 2 
condition: 2<3(true) returns true and next() gets you the list.get(current)


Size:3
current :3
Condition : 3<3(fail) you don't have anymore element to iterate as you reached to the end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you are doing in `next` method. Check the code from [ArrayList.Itr](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#753) implementation. Here is one way of implementing scenario you described(this is similar to ArrayList.Itr implementation),

- `current` initially points to 0.
- When `next` is called, current value of `current` is saved to a variable, say, `i`. `current` is incremented.
- The value at index `i` is returned.

In above case if the `current` value is 3, there are no more elements. The logic is right. The iterator have elements as long as `current<size`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it hasn't given the value at the index `current` yet. The function `hasNext` just tells you if there is something left to get out of an Iterator. For example if you'd like to print all the contents of an Iterator you would do something like this:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.print(iterator.next());
}
```

Where the functions `hasNext` and `next` would be defined as something like:

```
public boolean hasNext() {
    return current < this.size;
}
public T next() {
    return this.array[current];
    current++;
}
```